# How to get the Creator of an facebook fanpage.

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Is it possible to get a list of the fans, but in order of first to last? I am trying to see who the creator is of a certain page?

Comment: So you assumes the first fans is always the administrator ?

Comment: In most cases it would be, surely? I actually want to know the "CREATOR", which surely has to be the first fan, right?

Comment: Yes creator is the first.

Comment: I'm afraid that it is not possible ( in this way ). There is an connection between page and admins but to use the connection you need to be an administrator of that page. The connection to likes just contains an userID and no time-stamp or something where you can see who was first.

Comment: You can use the FQL: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page_fan there you will find a timestamp of when the user liked the page. ( note, does an administrator need to like the page? else it can false data)